# How to prevent duplicate travis build requests with different results, when pushing with tags

Tags: git, travis-ci

My build script creates a new release, adds a tag, commits, and pushes to GitHub with `--follow-tags` option.
This typically results in two build requests with identical hash but different results:

[image: travis build list]

The travis skript trigger some sauce-labs test suite, but 443 failed, probably because build 444 was started at nearly the same time:

[image]

As you can see, The badge on the travis site considers this 'build passing', but on the GitHub page this is not always the case:

[image]

So my questions are:

- This problem occurs sporadically with `git push --follow-tags` as well as with
  `git push && git push --tags`.
  Is there another way?
- Couldn't build 443 be silently skipped, if a second trigger with the same hash appears within some short time range?
  Or could travis simply acept the test result from the previous run: if the hash is the same, the code is identical, so the test results should be as well(?)
- I often can resolve this by restarting build 443 on the travis site.
  But this seems like a waste of travis and sauce-lab ressources.
  Is there a better way?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if it is acceptable for you but you can simply skip build with tag set:

```
script:
    - if [ -n "$TRAVIS_TAG" ]; then exit 0; fi
    - standard build command
```

Comment: thanks, I could try that. But this still feels like a workaround for a problem that has its root cause on the travis side (or a misunderstanding on my side)